# Add Custom Endpoint For Service ( Feathersjs )

Tags: node.js, api, feathersjs

I am new to NodeJS world.
I found    [FeatherJS](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/)     is a awesome tools/framework to build API service with very less Coding

I need to add a custom service endpoint (like : localhost/servicename/custom-end-point ). I also need to grab data from user in those end-point (could be a get request or post).

I have already gone through followings links, but nothing is clearly mention there,

https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/services.html 
https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [feathers-cli](https://github.com/feathersjs/cli) using the following command: `npm install -g @feathersjs/cli`.

To create a service, navigate to your project directory and run this command `feathers generate service`. It will ask some questions like service name.

If you don't already have an app then run this command to create one: `feathers generate app`.

Thats it!

---

**Update:**

Lets assume you have a service named `organizations` and you want to create a custom endpoint like `custom-organization`. Now, create a file inside **services > organizations** named `custom-organizations.class.js`. Add the following line in your `organizations.service.js` file.

```
// Import custom class
const { CustomOrganizations } = require('./custom-organizations.class');

// Initialize custom endpoint    
app.use('/custom-organizations', new CustomOrganizations(options, app));
```

Add the following code in your `custom-organizations.class.js` file.

```
const { Service } = require('feathers-mongoose');
exports.CustomOrganizations = class CustomOrganizations extends Service {
  constructor(options, app) {
    super(options);
  }

  async find() {
    return 'Test data';
  }
};
```

Now, if you send a get request to `/custom-organizations` endpoint then you should get `Test data`.

Hope it helps.

Wrote an article about it [here](https://anotherdev.xyz/feathersjs-custom-route-without-service/).

Comment: Thnaks, I know that, but i need to extra endpoint to a existing service, which will point to a custom service method

Comment: @Ahadul, check the updated answer. I am using latest version of FeathersJS.

Comment: Thanks Man, Really helpful. Can i able to CRUD action(of any service) inside custom-organizations.class.jsthis file, can you help me with that? if i use const service = app.service('organizations');code my app crash.

Comment: CRUD should be available inside custom-organizations (not sure). `const service = app.service('organizations');` did you mean `custom-organizations`?

Comment: Yes i need to do CRUD inside CustomOrganizations Class(file name :custom-organizations.class.js ) .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202623/discussion-between-ahadul-and-dijkstra).